# seahorse won't run, how to remove old version properly?

Tags: uninstall, seahorse

[image: Passwords and Keys]

Passwords and Keys alias `seahorse` won't run if clicked on.

When launched from terminal, I get this error:

```
seahorse: error while loading shared libraries: libldap_r-2.4.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

When trying to find such package and possibly install it I get:

```
$ apt-cache policy 'libldap*'
libldap2:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
libldap-common:
  Installed: 2.5.13+dfsg-0ubuntu0.22.04.1
  Candidate: 2.5.13+dfsg-0ubuntu0.22.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 2.5.13+dfsg-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.5.11+dfsg-1~exp1ubuntu3.1 500
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main i386 Packages
     2.5.11+dfsg-1~exp1ubuntu3 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 Packages
libldap-ocaml-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.4.2-1build3
  Version table:
     2.4.2-1build3 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 Packages
libldap-dev:
  Installed: 2.5.13+dfsg-0ubuntu0.22.04.1
  Candidate: 2.5.13+dfsg-0ubuntu0.22.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 2.5.13+dfsg-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.5.11+dfsg-1~exp1ubuntu3.1 500
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 Packages
     2.5.11+dfsg-1~exp1ubuntu3 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
libldap-ocaml-dev-vpsg7:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
libldap-2.3-0:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
libldap-2.4-2:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
libldap-2.5-0:
  Installed: 2.5.13+dfsg-0ubuntu0.22.04.1
  Candidate: 2.5.13+dfsg-0ubuntu0.22.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 2.5.13+dfsg-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.5.11+dfsg-1~exp1ubuntu3.1 500
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 Packages
     2.5.11+dfsg-1~exp1ubuntu3 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
libldap-java:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 5.0.0+dfsg1-1
  Version table:
     5.0.0+dfsg1-1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe i386 Packages
libldap2-dev:
  Installed: 2.5.13+dfsg-0ubuntu0.22.04.1
  Candidate: 2.5.13+dfsg-0ubuntu0.22.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 2.5.13+dfsg-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.5.11+dfsg-1~exp1ubuntu3.1 500
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main i386 Packages
     2.5.11+dfsg-1~exp1ubuntu3 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 Packages
$ sudo apt-get --simulate install libldap-2.4-2
[sudo] password for vlastimil:                
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package libldap-2.4-2 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  libldap-common

E: Package 'libldap-2.4-2' has no installation candidate
$ sudo apt-get --simulate install libldap-2.4
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libldap-2.4-2' for regex 'libldap-2.4'
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

```
$ which seahorse 
/usr/local/bin/seahorse
$ whereis seahorse
seahorse: /usr/bin/seahorse /usr/local/bin/seahorse /usr/libexec/seahorse /usr/share/seahorse /usr/share/man/man1/seahorse.1.gz
```

so naturally I tried `/usr/bin/seahorse` and I got it up and running:

[image: seahorse up and running]

So, I digged in Downloads directory, found:

```
/home/vlastimil/Downloads/seahorse/seahorse-3.31.91
```

with timestamp 2019-Feb-23. Built by `meson`, but how to remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you still have your full build tree, perhaps in `/home/vlastimil/Downloads/seahorse/seahorse-3.31.91/build`, then either

```sh
cd /home/vlastimil/Downloads/seahorse/seahorse-3.31.91/build
sudo ninja uninstall
```

or

```sh
cd /home/vlastimil/Downloads/seahorse/seahorse-3.31.91/build
sudo make uninstall
```

should uninstall the `/usr/local` version of Seahorse.

If the build tree isn’t available, you’ll have to re-do the build step, ideally with the same parameters you used in 2019:

```
cd /home/vlastimil/Downloads/seahorse/seahorse-3.31.91
meson build
cd build && sudo ninja uninstall
```